# getElementById return null

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm new to meteor AND js but it's very exciting to learn this new stuff and to play with it.

I'm doing a little app with that (and with other things :p ):

In my client.html file:

```
<template name="input">
    <form action={{submit}}>
    <p>
        Name : <input type="text" id="BibiName">
        Message : <input type="text" id="BibiMessage">
        <input type="submit" value="Toto">
    </p>
    </form>
</template>
```

In my client.js file:

```
Template.input.submit = function () {
    alert(document.getElementById("BibiName" ));
}
```

Result:
A pop window wit "null".

What am I doing wrong ?

Is is because execution of "submit function" in client.js file occurs before creation of "BibiName input" in client.html ?

Thx for your tips

Comment: Yes..Element must exist in the DOM before you can call `getElementById` otherwise it returns null

Comment: Thx u laaposto. Can you suggest me a tutorial where I can learn more about "what element is executed first, then 2nd,..." ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a listener for when the form is submitted, use [Template.myTemplate.events](http://docs.meteor.com/#template%5fevents) instead.